# Beginner JS Questions – Puppeteer.Js, Storing Data, Linking JSON Files, and For Loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm pretty new to front end dev. Going through the FCC Javascript course right now and am almost done! While FCC is good at teaching theory, they actually don't teach any of the basic actual programming setup (coding environment, json, etc).

**Scenario:**
I want to practice using Puppeteer to gather data from IMDB (Collecting Titles, Ratings, etc.) The tutorial I watched showed me how to do it 1 URL at a time. I am familiar with loops and arrays. Here is what I have so far. It works with *individual* URLs in generating Title and rating information.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
//const jsonFile = require("./data.json") >> not sure if this is correct
//const numberOfUrls = jsonFile.url.length; >> not sure if this is correct
//const urlsArray = jsonFile.url; >> not sure if this is correct

(async () => {

let movieUrl = 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0944947/';
  
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  
  await page.goto((movieUrl), { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });

  
  let data = await page.evaluate(() => {

    let title = document.querySelector('div[class="title_wrapper"] > h1').innerText;
    let rating = document.querySelector('span[itemprop="ratingValue"]').innerText;
    let ratingCount = document.querySelector('span[itemprop="ratingCount"]').innerText;
    
    return {
      title,
      rating,
      ratingCount
    }
  });
  
  console.log(data);

  await browser.close();
})();
```

I then manually (I don't know how to create a json file yet) created a data.json file within the same directory with the following information.

```
[
{"url":  "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5491994/"},
{"url": "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0795176/"},
{"url": "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0185906/"},
{"url":"https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0903747/"},
{"url": "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7366338/"},
{"url": "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0306414/"},
{"url": "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6769208/"}
]
```

**I have 4 questions:**

1. How do I 'link' a json file to my index.js file?
2. Is it better practice to create an obj with an array inside or an array with multiple objects inside?
3. Is it possible to save the results of a console.log to a brand new json file?
4. Can someone help me write a for loop to have my script iterate through my json file? Here is what I have so far...

```
for (let i = 0; i < numberOfUrls; i++) {
  await page.goto(urlsArray[i]);
  
  
  result.push();
}

console.log(result);
```

This is my very fist post on stack overflow. I decided to study programming to broaden employment prospects. I'd be happy to receive any feedback of ways in which I can improve my answer-seeking process (i.e. posted too much code, not enough context, etc.)

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Please revise your post and title to ask a single, clear, specific question. Don't make everyone wander in to see what you're on about. :)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You need to not ask multiple things in a post.

Answer (score 1):

In the future, try to use one question per a problem :)

1. Using JSON data files with `require` now is more or less a hack. It is more appropriate to use [`fs`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) module with [`JSON` methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON). Thus you will be independent from CommonJS module system and also will be able to use the same API for saving JSON.
2. Try to use the simplest data structure you can. In your case there is only one field in the objects, so just an array of strings suffices.

```json
[
  "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5491994/",
  "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0795176/",
  "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0185906/",
  "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0903747/",
  "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7366338/",
  "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0306414/",
  "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6769208/"
]
```

3. It is better to collect all the data first and then save it to the JSON file.
4. An example:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');

const json = fs.readFileSync('./test.json', 'utf8');
const urlsArray = JSON.parse(json);
const numberOfUrls = urlsArray.length;

(async () => {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    const result = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < numberOfUrls; i++) {
      await page.goto(urlsArray[i], { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });

      let data = await page.evaluate(() => {
        let title = document.querySelector('div[class="title_wrapper"] > h1').innerText;
        let rating = document.querySelector('span[itemprop="ratingValue"]').innerText;
        let ratingCount = document.querySelector('span[itemprop="ratingCount"]').innerText;

        return {
          title,
          rating,
          ratingCount
        };
      });

      console.log(data);
      result.push(data);
    }

    console.log(result);
    fs.writeFileSync('./result.json', JSON.stringify(result, null, 2), 'utf8');

    await browser.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```